# Internationalization in spring-boot and thymeleaf implementation

Tags: spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf

I'm trying to implement Internationalization in spring-boot and thymeleaf project and not getting expected results.  [This is current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQoeM.png)

Provided my code and property files content below.  My property files path is: `src/main/resources`

Would appreciate your guidance with this. Thank you.

**HTML Code:**

```
<body>
    <h1 th:text="#{index.title}">Library</h1>
    <a th:href="@{/books.html}" href="#" th:text="#{index.books.link}">List of books</a>
</body>
```

**messages_zh_CN.properties**

```
main.title=Spring Boot Recipes - 图书馆
index.title=图书馆
index.books.link=图书列表
books.list.title=可用图书
books.list.table.title=标题
books.list.table.author=作者
books.list.table.isbn=ISBN
```

**messages.properties**

```
main.title=Spring Boot Recipes - Library
index.title=Library
index.books.link=List of books
books.list.title=Available Books
books.list.table.title=Title
books.list.table.author=Author
books.list.table.isbn=ISBN
```

Comment: my  messages.properties in src/main/resources

Comment: Did you set any `LocaleResolver` as a Spring configuration

Comment: i set LocaleResolver localeResolver() function, but reload page dispaly ??main.language.en_en??,  en_en is odd character, i do not know where set error is? is file enconding or other. i don't know. i hope you tell me how to do .

Comment: i find reason. display ??main.language.en_en?? reason is messages.properties file encoding.  thanks your reply very much.